# Making simple HomeKit app from tutorial and getting error appending HMAccessory

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, homekit

I am following this tutorial:
http://www.xmcgraw.com/learn-how-to-create-an-ios-app-using-homekit/
There is a link in the article to GitHub that has the code.

I'm trying to get a simple HomeKit app up and running to turn on and off a light. I've read through Apple's guide to getting started with HomeKit. I do have a paid Apple developer membership and the provisioning profile allows me to build the app and run it on my iPhone (6s with iOS 10.2). I am using Xcode 8.2.1 and I have the HomeKit Accessory Simulator working and I can see the simulated lights I've created because I can print them to the console, they all show up by name.

The problem is, I cannot add them to the accessories array and get them added to the table view as cells. I have checked and re checked that the reuse identifier "accessoryId" on my cells matches what I'm using in my code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "accessoryId")  as UITableViewCell? {
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "accessoryId")
        let accessory = accessories[indexPath.row] as HMAccessory
        cell.textLabel?.text = accessory.name
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

I've looked through many other questions on SO regarding the same error and none of the fixes seemed to help.

When accessories.append(accessory) is commented out, the print function will console log all of the names of the found accessories from the simulator correctly.

```
func accessoryBrowser(_ browser: HMAccessoryBrowser, didFindNewAccessory accessory: HMAccessory) {
    print(accessory.name)

    accessories.append(accessory)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

but when I uncomment accessories.append(accessory), I get this error

> UITableView... failed to obtain a cell from its datasource"

[image: error]

How can I solve it?

Comment: That error indicates that it couldn't dequeue a cell with the identifier `"accessoryId"` - Double check your storyboard and make sure you have set the cell reuse identifier in the prototype cell

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't make sense for me:

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "accessoryId")
```

You are registering cell for table inside cellForRowAtIndexPath and every time it's called. Try to put it in viewDidLoad. But I'm think that you don't need to do that at all if you are using storyboards.

And in this is syntax in Swift 3 (your question title says you are using that):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "accessoryId") {
    // OR for Custom Cell:
    // if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "accessoryId") as? CustomTableViewCell {
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```